# How to configure .npmrc file to be able to combine different NPM registries?

Tags: npm-install, artifactory, npm-registry, .npmrc

How to set an `.npmrc` file to tell `npm install` to download all the dependencies from https://registry.npmjs.org but only a specific one from a corporate Artifactory under https://artifactory.corporation.io/artifactory/npm/ that needs authentication using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can configure https://registry.npmjs.org as a remote repository(test-npm-remote) in Artifactory. If you have any packages which were developed locally can be deployed to the local(test-npm-local) repository. We can create a virtual repository that consists of local and remote repositories and pull the npm artifacts using the virtual repository(test-npm). You can find more details in the below link.
https://jfrog.com/screencast/setting-up-an-npm-registry-with-jfrog-artifactory-in-less-than-one-minute/

```html
npm config set registry http://art.local/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/
npm login
<enter credentials>
```

Sample NPM client configuration for your reference.

```html
$ cat ~/.npmrc                                                                    
email=test@test.com
always-auth=true
registry=http://art.local/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/
//art.local/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/:username=testuser
//art.local/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/:_password=XXXXXXX
```

To install a package: npm install <PACKAGE_NAME>

Comment: @TataroVana are these lines comments ? :
`//art.local/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/:username=testuser
//art.local/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/:_password=XXXXXXX`

Comment: @Ghassen These lines are no comments. This is how you pass the username and password. You can find the same on the Set Me Up page of Artifactory.